# Compare between two specs values, Clojure.spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I have defined specs as -

```
(s/def ::start integer?)
(s/def ::end integer?)
(s/def ::collection (s/keys :req-un [::start ::end]))
```

It is working fine as `(s/valid? ::collection {:start 9 :end 13})`

But now I also have to check that `start` should be less than `end`. How to do that? Is there a simpler way to do that without creating an another fn and check?

Comment: Please remember accepting @edvorg answer, since your comments indicate it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spec's `s/def` definitions are just predicates. You can use `s/and` in the body of your `::collection` spec, where the first condition would be what you currently have and second would the order predicate:

```
(s/def ::ordered-collection (fn [{:keys [start end]}] (< start end)))

(s/def ::collection (s/and (s/keys :req-un [::start ::end])
                           ::ordered-collection))
```

Comment: It is giving an error. Unable to resolve spec: :structure  clojure.spec.alpha/reg-resolve! (alpha.clj:69)

Comment: Sorry fixed the solution, didn't have means to check it. You could check the proper signature for `and` function using repl.